# Import Data with Commas into Term Reference Field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, feeds

I'm having some difficulties to use feeds to import data that with commas.

I have a content type named device, and device has a field named features. features is supposed to be checkbox type which allows users to select multiple options from the provided list like A, B, C, D and the field type is `term reference`

I'm using feeds to map features column from a csv file to the features of device. When I do the import, instead of importing A, B, C, D separately, it created a new option as A, B, C, D altogether.

Is there anyway to separate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Feeds Tamper module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper), you can explode that field, then use ", " (comma space) as the separator.